how can i convert a python list into a file?
i am doing a python OOP exercise and i want to convert a list into containing variables such as name, age and job into a file, i tried 2 methods but just one worked, this was the one that worked (also the whole code)
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, job, age):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.age = age


class PersonManagement:
    def __init__(self):
        self.persons = []

    def add_person(self, name, job, age):
        person = Person(name, job, age)
        self.persons.append(person)

    def persons_file(self):
        with open("persons_file", "w") as file:
            for line in self.persons:
                file.write(f"{line.name} \n")

the class method named persons_file is the one i used to make the file, i did that, but, the thing is if i put online write(line) it only writes the memory addres, i solved that by writing the name Person's name attribute but i want the whole instance written in the file, how can i do that? i want name, age and job there

You know how to write the name. What specific problem are you having with doing the same for the age and job?

so, i just write it attribute after attribute? like this?: line.name, line.age, line.job
is there no better way? @user2357112

Of course there is a better way. Use proper serialization strategies, e.g. pydantic to store it as JSON. Or even easier depending on your case, use pickle. Beware that pickle is quite sensitive to version changes if you serialize framework classes with it.

"i want the whole instance written in the file" To clarify your question, please show an example of expected output file content. It would also help us give better advice if you tell us what the file is going to be used for.

You can convert Person into a dataclass, so it's easier to work with in your context. By overwriting the __str__ method we can customize how the data will be represented when it is cast to a str. All members of __persons are cast to str and written to the file.
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import json


@dataclass
class Person:
    name:str
    age:int
    job:str
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ', '.join(map(str, asdict(self).values()))


class PersonManagement:
    DEFAULT_FILE = "persons_file.json"

    def __init__(self, fp:str|None = None):
        # private vars - no external/remote access
        self.__persons = [] 
        self.__fp      = fp or PersonManagement.DEFAULT_FILE
        
    @property 
    def persons(self) -> list: 
        # copy, maintain no modifiable access to `__persons` or it's members
        # indexes reformatted to str
        return [*map(str, self.__persons)]

    # if `save` is a str it will be considered a filepath
    def append(self, *args, save:bool|str=False, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.__persons.append(Person(*args, **kwargs))
        if save: self.save((self.__fp, save)[isinstance(save, str)])

    # format and save `__persons` as comma-separated strings
    def save(self, fp:str|None = None) -> None:
        with open(fp or self.__fp, "w") as file:
            file.write(',\n'.join(p for p in self.persons))


Having a generic text file with arbitrary data in it is not very useful. You can switch to the json package to store the information in a way that you can easily reload. Below is a working example of one way you could structure your program to have a complete in/out system. The only real changes we have made here are:

Person is mapped to dict instead of str
json is used to format the dict to JSON
the file is saved as json
a load method is introduced

from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import json


@dataclass
class Person:
    name:str
    age:int
    job:str


class PersonManagement:
    DEFAULT_FILEPATH = "persons_file.json"

    def __init__(self, fp:str|None = None):
        # private vars - no external/remote access
        self.__persons = [] 
        self.__fp      = fp or PersonManagement.DEFAULT_FILEPATH
        
    @property 
    def persons(self) -> list: 
        # copy, maintain no modifiable access to `__persons` or it's members
        # indexes reformatted to dict
        return [*map(asdict, self.__persons)]

    # if `save` is a str it will be considered a filepath
    # `save` must be set via keyword
    def append(self, *args, save:bool|str=False, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.__persons.append(Person(*args, **kwargs))
        if save: self.save((self.__fp, save)[isinstance(save, str)])

    # format and save `__persons` as json
    def save(self, fp:str|None = None) -> None:
        with open(fp or self.__fp, "w") as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(self.persons, indent=4, default=str))
    
    # overwrite `__persons` from json        
    def load(self, fp:str|None = None) -> None:
        with open(fp or self.__fp, "r") as file:
            self.__persons = [Person(**data) for data in json.load(file)]


Using JSON for this might be fine, but there are a number of reasons why it isn't that great. For instance: if you used the shelve package, you could simply store each person directly to the database. You don't need to load the entire database to get data, and you don't need to overwrite the entire database to add data. The syntax for working with a shelve database is mostly the same as dict.

omg, thank you so much @OysterShucker, i researched about dataclass and now i know how to get data in a good way, thank you.
